# How to build legend for predictions in ```ggplot```?

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I ran a `glm()` evaluating the influence of canopy cover and vegetation density on temperature. I have graphed the raw data and included trend lines for the relationship between canopy cover and temperature below (thanks to very helpful people on here) at varying levels of vegetation density using `stat_function()`. I need the lines to be colored representing the different values of vegetation density and a corresponding legend like the one pictured below. How can I do this?

[image: Legend I want]

```
structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A1", "A10", "A100", "A11", "A12", "A13", 
"A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", "A18", "A19", "A2", "A20", "A21", 
"A22", "A23", "A24", "A25", "A26", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A3", 
"A30", "A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38", 
"A39", "A4", "A40", "A41", "A42", "A43", "A44", "A45", "A46", 
"A47", "A48", "A49", "A5", "A50", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", 
"A55", "A56", "A57", "A58", "A59", "A6", "A60", "A61", "A62", 
"A63", "A64", "A65", "A66", "A67", "A68", "A69", "A7", "A70", 
"A71", "A72", "A73", "A74", "A75", "A76", "A77", "A78", "A79", 
"A8", "A80", "A81", "A82", "A83", "A84", "A85", "A86", "A87", 
"A88", "A89", "A9", "A90", "A91", "A92", "A93", "A94", "A95", 
"A96", "A97", "A98", "A99", "B1", "B10", "B100", "B11", "B12", 
"B13", "B14", "B15", "B16", "B17", "B18", "B19", "B2", "B20", 
"B21", "B22", "B23", "B24", "B25", "B26", "B27", "B28", "B29", 
"B3", "B30", "B31", "B32", "B33", "B34", "B35", "B36", "B37", 
"B39", "B4", "B40", "B41", "B42", "B43", "B44", "B45", "B46", 
"B47", "B48", "B49", "B5", "B50", "B51", "B52", "B53", "B54", 
"B55", "B56", "B57", "B58", "B59", "B6", "B60", "B61", "B62", 
"B63", "B64", "B65", "B66", "B67", "B68", "B69", "B7", "B71", 
"B72", "B73", "B74", "B75", "B76", "B77", "B78", "B79", "B8", 
"B80", "B81", "B82", "B83", "B84", "B85", "B86", "B87", "B88", 
"B89", "B9", "B90", "B91", "B92", "B93", "B94", "B95", "B96", 
"B97", "B98", "B99"), class = "factor"), Temp_C = c(23.484, 23.388, 
23.677, 24.738, 24.738, 24.255, 32.704, 35.222, 28.456, 43.238
), Temp_F = c(74.2712, 74.0984, 74.6186, 76.5284, 76.5284, 75.659, 
90.8672, 95.3996, 83.2208, 109.8284), Type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Long = c(-97.47462153, -97.47462153, 
-97.47462153, -97.47462153, -97.47462153, -97.47462153, -97.47462153, 
-97.47462153, -97.47462153, -97.47462153), Lat = c(26.58459955, 
26.58459955, 26.58459955, 26.58459955, 26.58459955, 26.58459955, 
26.58459955, 26.58459955, 26.58459955, 26.58459955), landcover_class5m = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Woody", "Grassland", 
"Bareground", "Water"), class = "factor"), can_cover1m = c(0.474885043425438, 
0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 
0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 
0.474885043425438), veg_density1m = c(14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 
14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 
14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175
), X = c(2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 
2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 
2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244), Y = c(651903.662642045, 
651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 
651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 
651903.662642045), DateTime = structure(c(1560884400, 1560886200, 
1560889800, 1560891600, 1560893400, 1560958200, 1560960000, 1560961800, 
1560963600, 1560965400), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Time = c("14:00:00", "14:30:00", "15:30:00", "16:00:00", 
"16:30:00", "10:30:00", "11:00:00", "11:30:00", "12:00:00", "12:30:00"
), Date = structure(c(18065, 18065, 18065, 18065, 18065, 18066, 
18066, 18066, 18066, 18066), class = "Date"), AvgTemp_C = c(37.4423161407767, 
37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 
37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 
37.4423161407767), MedTemp_C = c(38.046, 38.046, 38.046, 38.046, 
38.046, 38.046, 38.046, 38.046, 38.046, 38.046), MaxTemp_C = c(46.083, 
46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 
46.083)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(Id = structure(1L, .Label = c("A1", 
"A10", "A100", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", 
"A18", "A19", "A2", "A20", "A21", "A22", "A23", "A24", "A25", 
"A26", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A3", "A30", "A31", "A32", "A33", 
"A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38", "A39", "A4", "A40", "A41", 
"A42", "A43", "A44", "A45", "A46", "A47", "A48", "A49", "A5", 
"A50", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", "A55", "A56", "A57", "A58", 
"A59", "A6", "A60", "A61", "A62", "A63", "A64", "A65", "A66", 
"A67", "A68", "A69", "A7", "A70", "A71", "A72", "A73", "A74", 
"A75", "A76", "A77", "A78", "A79", "A8", "A80", "A81", "A82", 
"A83", "A84", "A85", "A86", "A87", "A88", "A89", "A9", "A90", 
"A91", "A92", "A93", "A94", "A95", "A96", "A97", "A98", "A99", 
"B1", "B10", "B100", "B11", "B12", "B13", "B14", "B15", "B16", 
"B17", "B18", "B19", "B2", "B20", "B21", "B22", "B23", "B24", 
"B25", "B26", "B27", "B28", "B29", "B3", "B30", "B31", "B32", 
"B33", "B34", "B35", "B36", "B37", "B39", "B4", "B40", "B41", 
"B42", "B43", "B44", "B45", "B46", "B47", "B48", "B49", "B5", 
"B50", "B51", "B52", "B53", "B54", "B55", "B56", "B57", "B58", 
"B59", "B6", "B60", "B61", "B62", "B63", "B64", "B65", "B66", 
"B67", "B68", "B69", "B7", "B71", "B72", "B73", "B74", "B75", 
"B76", "B77", "B78", "B79", "B8", "B80", "B81", "B82", "B83", 
"B84", "B85", "B86", "B87", "B88", "B89", "B9", "B90", "B91", 
"B92", "B93", "B94", "B95", "B96", "B97", "B98", "B99"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
middayglm <- glm(AvgTemp_C ~ can_cover1m + veg_density1m, data=midday)


Call:
glm(formula = AvgTemp_C ~ can_cover1m + veg_density1m, data = midday)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-7.6512  -0.8557   0.1114   0.9987   3.3244  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   39.8968032  0.0066905 5963.17   <2e-16 ***
can_cover1m   -6.0778158  0.0150905 -402.76   <2e-16 ***
veg_density1m  0.0041058  0.0003364   12.21   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 2.473566)

    Null deviance: 1259787  on 256593  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  634695  on 256591  degrees of freedom
AIC: 960574

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

```
equation25 = function(x){coef(middayglm)[2]*x+coef(middayglm)[1]+0.25}
equation50 = function(x){coef(middayglm)[2]*x+coef(middayglm)[1]+0.50}
equation75 = function(x){coef(middayglm)[2]*x+coef(middayglm)[1]+0.75}

midday_grid <- crossing(can_cover1m = seq(0, 1, length.out = 2), veg_density1m = c(1, 50, 99))

midday_grid_with_preds <- predict(midday_grid)

#
middayglm_plot <- ggplot(midday,aes(y=AvgTemp_C ,x=can_cover1m,)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) +
  stat_function(fun=equation25,geom="line",size = 2,color='blue') +
  stat_function(fun=equation50,geom="line",size = 2,color='gray') +
  stat_function(fun=equation75,geom="line",size = 2,color='gray') +
  scale_colour_manual("Vegetation Density", values = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.30), limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(30, 45, by = 5), limits=c(30,45)) +
  labs(title='Midday 09:00 - 16:59',x='% Canopy Cover', y='Average Temperature (C)', color='Vegetation Density')  +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=30),axis.title=element_text(size=30,face="bold"), 
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=30)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=30, face='bold'),legend.title = element_text(size=30), legend.text = element_text(size=20),
        legend.key.size = unit(2, 'cm')) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
middayglm_plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```r
library(ggeffects)
data(mtcars)
m <- glm(mpg ~ wt + disp, data=mtcars)
g <- ggpredict(m, terms=c("wt [all]", "disp [121, 196, 326]"))
plot(g, ci=FALSE, raw=TRUE)
#> Loading required namespace: ggplot2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note: I couldn't use your data because the vegetation density variable didn't vary (it was constant for the observations shown).  This is an similar example using the `mtcars` data. If you're only going to have three lines, it's probably better to treat them as a factor rather than continuous when colouring the lines.